# What are some good Wireshark tutorials?

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to understand how to use Wireshark right now, but the [official manual](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/index.html) isn't a fun read at all when starting out. Its too detailed, and the details are going right over my head because of the information overloading :)

What are some more didactic tutorials out there?

Thanks!

**Edit:** WireShark is a network packet sniffer, and it's very useful for debugging network applications. I'm working on networked applications, and plan to use it as a Debugging tool to make my job as a programmer happier. I guess this is about programming related as asking for tutorials about gbd, valgrind or mdb, dtrace, prstat, cat, visual studio or eclipse.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some details on how this is related to programming.

Comment: I use Ethereal, it's predecessor, to analyze HTTP traffic and diagnose communication issues, and as such this is very related to programming.

Comment: Wireshark is an awesome low level debug tool for socket programming. So it's extremely relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't start with a tutorial on Wireshark itself necessarily. Reading the Wireshark manual first is kind of like reading the help guide to Visual Studio; if you already knew the basics of how programming is done the IDE would naturally make a lot of sense.

If you google and find some tutorials on Ethernet in general (the structure of packets, how TCP and UDP data gets from point A to point B, etc) then the information Wireshark presents will make sense naturally.

For extra bonus points check out Cisco's OSI model - if you can understand each layer of that then you'll have a deep understanding of what Wireshark is telling you.

If you just want a quickstart: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bazkLeY6b4

Comment: Thanks, but I know enough about the protocols, but I have no idea how to take advantage of the tool. It looks wonderful, and its got all sort of bells and whistles, but I have no idea what levers to pull :)

Comment: Anything you're trying to do specifically?

Comment: in the long run I want to setup some scripts that will trigger alerts when bad data is sent along the pipes. But first I need to understand the tool in general

Comment: Added link to decent quick beginner video... you may already be above that level though.

Comment: Not bad, I had gotten about that far fumbling my way through the tool, but at least I now know that I wasn't doing stuff totally wrong!

Answer (score 3):

These should do it:

[Wireshark & Ethereal Network Protocol Analyzer Toolkit (Jay Beale's Open Source Security)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597490733)

[Practical Packet Analysis: Using Wireshark to Solve Real-World Network Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271492)